# Back EMF from a motor

Tags: motors, electrical

I have a large DC Motor I ripped out of a treadmill and I'm curious if the back emf generated from manually rotating the motor is a DC output or an AC output. Is it AC only when it's from the power grid and other sources treated as DC? How can I always tell?

For context, the motor is a 2.65Hp, 21.4A, P.M.D.C Motor

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Permanent Magnet DC motor, even if you rotate it with the constant rate the back EMF you'll get externally from the motor connector pins ought to be more *similar* to a rectified AC.

[image]

However, I wouldn't expect it to be exactly sinosoidal.

Comment: Is there a reason why it would look like this? From my understanding, the back EMF is proportional to the speed of the motor shaft and so, at steady-state where the speed of the motor is constant, wouldn't the back EMF approach a steady-state value and hence be a DC voltage?

Comment: The reason I expect it to be so (I've never actually measured this type of motor, although I have done measurement on wind turbines), is that the windings revolve in a don't go through a constant magnetic field, so there is this sinusoidal curve. Also the rectificiation is due to the commutators.

Comment: That's actually quite helpful and that checks out with me logically. I have seen that some of the large motors have a permanent magnet in them and with the rotation of the rotor, the generated voltage should behave as you say. Thank you very much!